# Meme Museum tutorial - 'exceed prepaid gas'

Tags: nearprotocol, near

Im getting this error. It seems to happen no matter how much gas I give it. Can someone help or advise what I am doing wrong? Thanks

````
Scheduling a call: museum.testnet.add_meme({"meme" : "andrew", "title" : "sweats", "data" : "https://9gag.com/gag/aVxM0B2", "category" : 4}) with attached 6 NEAR
Doing account.functionCall()
Receipts: BuNWjPmKBojGbjUs86EEpX1xrvC6AG5GacxX5xmTzSkk, 5PAK416Wn1F5AzHHz28fNa2dbHzWHFzKg2UoKCStfZ3U
    Log [museum.testnet]: attempting to create meme
    Failure [museum.testnet]: Error: {"index":0,"kind":{"ExecutionError":"Exceeded the prepaid gas."}}

Transaction 87djyBrCwgubEfsta68xPeRTy6VKShXMWEroSkvjDSY3 had 30000000000000 of attached gas but used 2428128941862 of gas
View this transaction in explorer: https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/87djyBrCwgubEfsta68xPeRTy6VKShXMWEroSkvjDSY3```
````

Comment: Does this post answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70452485/exceeded-prepaid-gas-common-solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to execute this properly you need to have both the `--amount 3` and the `--gas 300000000000000` parameters.

```
        near call museum.testnet add_meme '{ "meme": "coe", \ 
        "title": "roncoe", "data": "https://9gag.com/gag/ad8K0vj", \         
        "category": 4 }' --accountId youraccountid.testnet \
        --gas 300000000000000 --amount 3
```

Comment: Be advised that it is 14 zeros after the "3" for gas.

Answer (score 1):

Try attaching gas instead of deposit. Here's an example using the CLI:

```
near call museum.testnet add_meme --gas 300000000000000 --accountId=youraccount.testnet '{
  "meme": "bob",
  "title": "blabla",
  "data": "https://9gag.com/gag/ad8K0vj",
  "category": 4
}'
```

Comment: Thanks, that answers the question.